# how can i get current model item in mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this list view that include edit button leads to modal

```
<table class="table" id="table">
   @foreach (var item in Model.model2)
   {
   <tr>
      <td>
         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
      </td>
      <td>
         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.who_reply)
      </td>
      <td>
         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
      </td>
      <td>
         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Details)
      </td>
      <td>
         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reply_Id)
      </td>
      <td>
         <input class="edit" id="edit" type="button" value="edit" data-reply="@item.Details" data-Reply_Id="@item.Reply_Id" />
      </td>
   </tr>
   }
</table>
```

I wrote this jquery code to check Reply_Id value it works fine it gives me the current Reply_Id

```
$('.edit').click(function () {
  alert($(this).data('Reply_Id'));
  $('#ModalPopUp6').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
  $("#reply-text6").val($(this).data('reply'));
});
```

but the problem is that when I press save button in modal only get the first reply_id not the current:

```
$("#save").click(function () {
  alert($('.edit').data('Reply_Id'));
});
```

Comment: Not directly your problem, but note that `data-` should always be lowercase.

Comment: alert($(this).data('Reply_Id')) at $('.edit').click() is very speific <input> in a row where as $("#save").click() is first row. You should use dynamic class or id and load specific insted of generic or use .each().

Comment: thanks for your reply and the is no similar id i think there is a way to get the item at the same line in the list

Comment: You do have an issue with `<input id="edit"` but it's not causing your problem in this case as you're not referring to `$("#edit")` compare `$("#edit").length` (===1) with `$("[id=edit]").length` (=== number of rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is caused by

```
$(".class").data(dataname)
```

which  retrieves the *first* entry, you need to "store" which edit button (reply_id) was clicked - either in a simple variable or in a more robust method such as:

```
$('.edit').click(function () {
  // get the edit button's ID
  var id = $(this).data('Reply_Id');

  // store it against the modal
  $('#ModalPopUp6').data("replyid", id);

  $('#ModalPopUp6').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
  $("#reply-text6").val($(this).data('reply'));
});
```

then

```
$("#save").click(function () {
  // get the original row's ID from the modal
  var id = $('#ModalPopUp6').data("replyid");

  // find the matching button (then get the parent row for the whole record)
  var row = $("[data-Reply_id=" + id + "]").closest("tr");
});
```

Comment: thanks bro very smart man you mentioned that can i do it in simple variable or in a more robust method  so what is that simple

Comment: Simple variable would just be `var replyid` at the top level (global) and then `replyid = $(this).data('Reply_Id');` (without the var prefix) in the click method.  You could even store the button/row itself directly in the click method instead of the id.   However, global variables are generally considered not-best-practice, which is why I didn't include it.